# Firefox open url as pinned tab by default

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, browser-tabs

I want to open specific url as pinned tab by default. There is an extension for this in Chrome:
[Pin Tab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pin-tab/dgldedkigbbalaioohedddpameekglma?hl=en).

How to do this in firefox? I couldn't find a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly what you want to do, I would suggest

Tools
General
When Firefox starts: "Show my home page" or "Show my windows and tabs from last time"
Home Page: (here you will set the pages you want to be "pinned")

An easy way of doing this is to open all the pages you want to have pinned, close everything else, and the hit "Use Current Pages".

---

Thanks to the image and the explanation given in the comments, it turns out the way to do this in Firefox is to right-click the tab you want to pin, and choose "pin tab" from the context menu.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what a pinned tab in firefox is. (and probably chrome, too)

Comment: @egolus -- What's the difference, please?

Comment: @aparente001 -- Thank you for your answer, but what I really want is: when I open a new tab and write, lets say, example.com, right after I hit enter I would like to see that tab being pinned (like this: [PinnedTab](http://www.guidingtech.com/assets/postimages/2011/02/pintab2.png))

Comment: @spunky031 you can pin tabs in firefox by right-clicking and click `pin tap`. I don't know, if this is possible from a bookmark etc.

Comment: @aparente001 I interpret your answer that you think a pinned tab is a tab that gets reopened on restart. But to pin it means putting it all to the left and keeping it in front of all other if there are more tabs than space (see the image in the comment from spunky031). If you meant that, I'm sorry.

Comment: @egolus - Thank you, also the image helped.  I am now going to pin some of my tabs!